# Is sed \{x,y\} range greedy?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I would like to know if, for instance, `\{x,y\}` in `sed` will try to match as much or as little as possible characters.

Also, can someone explain to me the bellow unexpected behaviour of `sed`?

```
echo "baaab" | sed 's/a\{1,2\}//'
bab

echo "baaab" | sed 's/a\{0,2\}//'
baaab
```

In the first line, `sed` becomes greedy, in the second apparently it doesn't, is there a reason for that?

I'm using GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: Your first example by itself demonstrates that it is greedy.

Comment: If you watch closely, you'll notice that there are actually **two** examples, with two seemingly different behaviours. However thanks to those useful and constructive answers, I can know understand this behaviour ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`a\{0,2\}` will match the empty string at the start of the line (actually, any empty string, but `g` wasn't specified):

```
$ echo "baaab" | sed 's/a\{0,2\}/y/' 
ybaaab
```

Since GNU `sed` does matching from left to right, and a global replacement wasn't specified, only the start of the line matched. If you'd used `g`:

```
$ echo "baaab" | sed 's/a\{0,2\}/y/g'
ybyyby
```

The empty strings at the start and end matched, and the `aa`, and the remaining `a`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's greedy.

In POSIX compliant system, not only `sed` but also all tools which use [Basic Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), the [matched pattern will always be greedy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01_02):

> The search for a matching sequence starts at the beginning of a string
>   and stops when the first sequence matching the expression is found,
>   where "first" is defined to mean "begins earliest in the string". If
>   the pattern permits a variable number of matching characters and thus
>   there is more than one such sequence starting at that point, **the
>   longest such sequence is matched**. For example, the BRE "bb*" matches
>   the second to fourth characters of the string "abbbc", and the ERE
>   "(wee|week)(knights|night)" matches all ten characters of the string
>   "weeknights".
>
> Consistent with the whole match being the longest of the leftmost
>   matches, each subpattern, from left to right, shall match the longest
>   possible string. For this purpose, **a null string shall be considered
>   to be longer than no match at all**. For example, matching the BRE
>   "(.*).*" against "abcdef", the subexpression "(\1)" is "abcdef", and
>   matching the BRE "(a*)*" against "bc", the subexpression "(\1)" is
>   the null string.

The pattern `a\{0,2\}` matched any occurrence of character `a` between zero and two. Zero occurrence means the empty string, which is considered to be longer than no match as the spec indicated above.

The problem with your usage is that you did not use the `g`lobal flag for `sed` `s`ubstitution command. Without `g`lobal flag, `sed` stop doing `s`ubstitution as soon as it found the first match, which is the empty string at the beginning of the line.

---

The general form is `\{m,n\}` with `0 <= m <= n <= RE_DUP_MAX`, with `RE_DUP_MAX` is `32767` in most platform:

```
$ getconf RE_DUP_MAX
32767
```